# regex For Float Numbers with Limits

Tags: regex, regula

I need regex Expression for Floating and whole numbers that have the limit like it will accept 1 or 2 digit before point and 1 or 2 digits after point. Whole number limit should be 2 digit.
    What should be valid:

```
 - 1.1
 - 11.1
 - 1.11
 - 11.11
 - 2
 - 22

What should be invalid:

 - 111.111
 - 222
Here is my Regex:
/^\d{1,2}(\.\d){1,2}?$/


But it is not working properly
kindly help me in this
```

Comment: Are you coding in Swift/Objective-C? Then why use regex delimiters?

Comment: Try `^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$`

Comment: Are values like `1.` and `2.` valid?

Comment: M coding in react

Comment: No value like 1. 2. is not valid. There should be 1 or 2 digit after point.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following pattern:

```
^\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pcBx8P/1).

[image]

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\.` -  a dot
  - `\d{1,2}`  - 1 or 2 digits
- `$` -  end of string.

Comment: Wow, I like that slick graphic

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working perfectly. Can u Explain an optional sequence. \d{1,2} this is for the digit, \. this is for point , \d{1,2} this is for digit after point.  but ?: what is this. How it is working in the expression

Comment: @Fizzah `(?:...)` is a [**non-capturing group**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513858/3832970). It is used to only group patterns without storing the value captured in a memory buffer. What makes it optional is the `?` quantifier after it. The `?` makes the whole pattern inside the non-capturing group be matched 1 or 0 times.

Comment: Got it. Thank You so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

Making the 2nd part of the regex optional

Comment: Yeah, after a fix as per my comment above it will work, but there is no need using a capturing group, a non-capturing is enough. Now, our solutions are almost identical.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your answer is much better, where did you make that graphic from?